# Java Maze - Visited Cells Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, maze

I am working on solving this maze and I can't seem to get the ArrayList that holds the Points of the cells I've already visited correct. The solver just keeps flickering.

Here is my main class

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.*;

public class Program3
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

    Maze aMaze = new Maze(8, 10); //creates a 8x10 Maze
    MazeDisplay  display = new MazeDisplay(aMaze);  //creates a MazeDisplay with aMaze in it.
    aMaze.buildMaze(20); //builds maze

    //---- create a Stack to hold sequence of moves
    Stack<Maze.Direction> myMoves = new Stack<Maze.Direction>();

    //---- create a Stack of type Point to note whether a cell has been visited
    ArrayList<Point> visitedCells = new ArrayList<Point> ();

    //---- use a while loop to check if the cell is open, follows algorithm to efficiently move through maze. If no other moves
    //---- are available, it will pop the stack and go backward until it can move into a cell that has not been previously
    //---- visited.
     while (aMaze.goalReached() == false)
     {
         //---- create a new Point
        Point myCell = new Point(aMaze.getCurrentRow(), aMaze.getCurrentCol());
        visitedCells.add(myCell);

         //---- Step 1: check if the cell above is open. If so, move there, log that move in the stack, and mark visited.
         if (aMaze.open(Maze.Direction.UP) == true && (!visitedCells.contains(myCell.getX()) && !visitedCells.contains(myCell.getY()-1)))
         {
             myCell.setLocation(aMaze.getCurrentRow(), aMaze.getCurrentCol());
             aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.UP);
             myMoves.push(Maze.Direction.UP);
             visitedCells.add(myCell);

         }
         //---- Step 2: check if the cell below is open. If so, move there, log that move in the stack, and mark visited.
         else if (aMaze.open(Maze.Direction.DOWN) == true && (!visitedCells.contains(myCell.getX()) && !visitedCells.contains(myCell.getY()+1)))
         {
             myCell.setLocation(aMaze.getCurrentRow(), aMaze.getCurrentCol());
             aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.DOWN);
             myMoves.push(Maze.Direction.DOWN);
             visitedCells.add(myCell);
         }
         //---- Step 3: check if the cell to left is open. If so, move there, log that move in the stack, and mark visited.
         else if (aMaze.open(Maze.Direction.LEFT) == true && (!visitedCells.contains(myCell.getX()-1) && !visitedCells.contains(myCell.getY())))
         {
             myCell.setLocation(aMaze.getCurrentRow(), aMaze.getCurrentCol()); 
             aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.LEFT);
             myMoves.push(Maze.Direction.LEFT);
             visitedCells.add(myCell);
         }
         //---- Step 4: check if the cell to right is open. If so, move there, log that move in the stack, and mark visited.
         else if (aMaze.open(Maze.Direction.RIGHT) == true && (!visitedCells.contains(myCell.getX()+1) && !visitedCells.contains(myCell.getY())))
         {
             myCell.setLocation(aMaze.getCurrentRow(), aMaze.getCurrentCol());
             aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.RIGHT);
             myMoves.push(Maze.Direction.RIGHT);
             visitedCells.add(myCell);
         }
         else
         {
            Maze.Direction var = myMoves.pop();
            if (var == Maze.Direction.RIGHT)
                aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.LEFT);
            else if (var == Maze.Direction.LEFT)
                aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.RIGHT);
            else if (var == Maze.Direction.DOWN)
                aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.UP);
            else if (var == Maze.Direction.UP)
                aMaze.move(Maze.Direction.DOWN);

         }
    }
    //---- jumps out of loop when solved, prints statement below.
    System.out.print("Maze is solved.");
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Maze class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Maze implements Serializable
{
//-------data
private int[ ][ ] mazeArray;
private int currentArrayRow;
private int currentArrayCol;
private int goalArrayRow;
private int goalArrayCol;
private int buildAnimationDelay;
private int solveAnimationDelay;
private boolean alreadyBuilt;

//-------constructors
public Maze(int numRealRows, int numRealCols)
{
    //since the maze is being created, initialize alreadyBuilt to false
    alreadyBuilt = false;

    //set the buildAnimationDelay and solveAnimationDelat to 0;  they can be reset with methods
    buildAnimationDelay = 0;
    solveAnimationDelay = 0;

    //make sure that the numRealRows and numRealCols are both > 1 (start cannot == goal)
    if (numRealRows < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of rows must be > 1");
    if (numRealCols < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of columns must be > 1");

    //create the 2D array to hold the maze (its even rows/cols hold the walls, odd rows/cols hold the paint
    mazeArray = new int[2*numRealRows+1][2*numRealCols+1];

    //since the even values are the walls, set anything with an even component to 1 (wall exists to start)
    for (int row=0; row<mazeArray.length; row++)
        for (int col=0; col<mazeArray[row].length; col++)
            if (row%2==0 || col%2==0)   //if either dimension is even...
                mazeArray[row][col] = 1;        //its a wall, so set value to 1

    //initialize the currentArrayRow and currentArrayCol to the upper left corner
    currentArrayRow = 1;
    currentArrayCol= 1;
}

// **************** methods *******************************************

//------- setSolveAnimationDelay - sets the delay (milliseconds) for the maze being solved (in case its animated)
public void setSolveAnimationDelay(int theDelay)
{
    solveAnimationDelay = theDelay;
}

//------- buildMaze - builds the Maze; calls other buildMaze method to set buildAnimationDelay to 0
public void buildMaze()
{
    buildMaze(0);
}

//------- buildMaze - builds the Maze; receives a delay to slow it down (in case its displayed)
public void buildMaze(int buildAnimationDelay)
{
    //if this maze has already been built and it trying to be built again, throw an exception
    if (alreadyBuilt)
        throw new IllegalStateException("cannot build maze - it has already been built");
    else
        alreadyBuilt = true;   //because we are NOW building it

    //create a Stack to hold the cells we are visiting as it is built (they will be stored as Points)
    //and an ArrayList to hold the "neighbors" in the code below
    Stack<Point> cellStack = new Stack<Point>();
    ArrayList<Point> neighborAL;

    //in the mazeArray, the even rows/cols are the walls, the odd rows/cols are the cells
    int numRealRows = mazeArray.length/2;
    int numRealCols = mazeArray[0].length/2;

    //calculate the total number of (real) cells to visit
    int totalCells = numRealRows * numRealCols;  //rows x cols

    //the odd rows/cols store the actual cells.  Choose a random cell to start.
    Random gen = new Random();
    int currentArrayRow = gen.nextInt(numRealRows)*2 + 1;   //ex: if 3 real rows, this is a random from 1,3,5
    currentArrayCol = gen.nextInt(numRealCols)*2 + 1;       //same for cols...
    int lastArrayRow = currentArrayRow;
    int lastArrayCol = currentArrayCol;

    mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 2;
    int numVisitedCells = 1;

    //while all cells have not been visited...
    while(numVisitedCells < totalCells)
    {
        //go to sleep to slow down animation (based on its speed)
        try{ Thread.sleep(buildAnimationDelay); }
        catch(Exception ex) {}

        //find all neighbors of currentCell with all walls intact
        neighborAL = new ArrayList<Point>();
        //try cell above it
        if (inMaze(currentArrayRow-2, currentArrayCol) && allWallsIntact(currentArrayRow-2, currentArrayCol))
            neighborAL.add(new Point(currentArrayRow-2, currentArrayCol));
        //try cell below it
        if (inMaze(currentArrayRow+2, currentArrayCol) && allWallsIntact(currentArrayRow+2, currentArrayCol))
            neighborAL.add(new Point(currentArrayRow+2, currentArrayCol));
        //try cell to the left of it
        if (inMaze(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol-2) && allWallsIntact(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol-2))
            neighborAL.add(new Point(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol-2));
        //try cell to the right of it
        if (inMaze(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol+2) && allWallsIntact(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol+2))
            neighborAL.add(new Point(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol+2));

        //if neighbors with intact walls exist...
        if (neighborAL.size() > 0)
        {
            //choose a neighbor at random
            int randomInt = gen.nextInt(neighborAL.size());
            Point theNeighbor = neighborAL.get(randomInt);
            int neighborRow = (int)theNeighbor.getX();
            int neighborCol = (int)theNeighbor.getY();

            //knock down the wall in between
            if (currentArrayRow != neighborRow)    //neighbor chosen was above or below
                mazeArray[(currentArrayRow+neighborRow)/2][currentArrayCol] = 0;   //knock down wall in between
            else if (currentArrayCol != neighborCol)   //neighbor chosen was to the left or right
                mazeArray[currentArrayRow][(currentArrayCol+neighborCol)/2] = 0;    //knock down wall in between

            //push the current cell onto the cellStack
            cellStack.push(new Point(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol));

            //clear the current cell
            mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 0;

            //make the new cell the current cell
            currentArrayRow = neighborRow;
            currentArrayCol = neighborCol;
            mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 2;

            //add 1 to visitedCells
            numVisitedCells++;
        }
        else
        {
            //clear the current cell
            mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 0;

            //pop the most recent entry off of cellStack and make it the current cell
            Point popped = cellStack.pop();
            currentArrayRow = (int)popped.getX();
            currentArrayCol = (int)popped.getY();
            mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 2;
        }
    }   //end while

    //clear the cell that ended up as the current Cell
    mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 0;

    //set the current cell to the upper left corner
    currentArrayRow = 1;
    currentArrayCol = 1;
    mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 2;   //current

    //set the goal to the lower right corner
    goalArrayRow = numRealRows*2-1;
    goalArrayCol = numRealCols*2-1;
    mazeArray[goalArrayRow][goalArrayCol] = 3;   //goal
}

//-------- allWallsIntact - returns true if the cell at [aRow][aCol] has all walls around it intact
private boolean allWallsIntact(int aRow, int aCol)
{
    return   (mazeArray[aRow-1][aCol] == 1   && //wall above it exists
                    mazeArray[aRow+1][aCol] == 1  &&    //wall below it exists
                    mazeArray[aRow][aCol-1] == 1   &&   //wall to the left exists
                    mazeArray[aRow][aCol+1] == 1);          //wall to the right exists
}

//-------- inMaze - returns true if the cell at [aRow][aCol] is in the maze
private boolean inMaze(int aRow, int aCol)
{
    return   (aRow > 0   &&   aRow < mazeArray.length-1   &&
                    aCol > 0     &&   aCol   < mazeArray[0].length-1);
}

//-------- getCurrentRow - returns the current (real) row
public int getCurrentRow()
{
    return currentArrayRow/2;
}

//-------- getCurrentCol - returns the current (real) col
public int getCurrentCol()
{
    return currentArrayCol/2;
}


//-------- open - returns true if there is no wall in the direction that is passed in
public boolean open(Direction direction)
{
    boolean result = false;
    if (direction == Direction.UP && mazeArray[currentArrayRow-1][currentArrayCol]==0)
        result = true;
    else if (direction == Direction.DOWN && mazeArray[currentArrayRow+1][currentArrayCol]==0)
        result = true;
    else if (direction == Direction.LEFT && mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol-1]==0)
        result = true;
    else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT && mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol+1]==0)
        result = true;

    return result;
}

//-------- openTo - returns true if the current cell is openTo (no wall) the one passed in
private boolean openTo(int aRow, int aCol)
{
    boolean result;

    if (!adjacentTo(aRow, aCol))
        result = false;
    else if (currentArrayRow-aRow == 2)  //IS adjacent, figure which direction and call other method
        result = mazeArray[currentArrayRow-1][currentArrayCol]==0;   //UP
    else if (currentArrayRow-aRow == -2)
        result = mazeArray[currentArrayRow+1][currentArrayCol]==0;   //DOWN
    else if (currentArrayCol-aCol == 2)
        result = mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol-1]==0;   //LEFT
    else if (currentArrayCol-aCol == -2)
        result = mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol+1]==0;   //RIGHT
    else
        result = false;

    return result;
}

//-------- adjacentTo - returns true if the current cell is adjacentTo (above/below/left/right) current cell
public boolean adjacentTo(int aRow, int aCol)
{
    //calculate how far the move is (hopefully row OR col is just +-2)
    int arrayRowChange = currentArrayRow - aRow;
    int arrayColChange = currentArrayCol - aCol;

    //it is adjacent if EITHER the rows or the cols differ by 2
    return Math.abs(arrayRowChange)==2 ^ Math.abs(arrayColChange)==2;  //checking row xor col
}

// -------- move - receives a Direction and moves there if OK.  Calls the other
//                 arrayMove to do this
public boolean move(Direction direction)
{
    boolean success = false;

    if (direction == Direction.UP)
        success = arrayMove(currentArrayRow-2, currentArrayCol);
    else if (direction == Direction.DOWN)
        success = arrayMove(currentArrayRow+2, currentArrayCol);
    else if (direction == Direction.LEFT)
        success = arrayMove(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol-2);
    else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT)
        success = arrayMove(currentArrayRow, currentArrayCol+2);

    return success;
}

//-------- move - receives the literal (not array) row/col to move to.  Calls the
//                other ArrayMove to do this.
private boolean move(int realRow, int realCol)
{
    return arrayMove(2*realRow+1, 2*realCol+1);
}

//-------- arrayMove - moves using the maze array (moves a distance of 2 to get to next cell)
//                     first checks to see if move is legal.
private boolean arrayMove(int newArrayRow, int newArrayCol)
{
    boolean success;

    //go to sleep to slow down animation (based on its speed)
    try{ Thread.sleep(solveAnimationDelay); }
    catch(Exception ex) {}

    //make sure the new row/col is still in the maze
    if (!inMaze(newArrayRow, newArrayCol))
        throw new IllegalMazeMoveException("trying to move to cell <" + newArrayRow/2 + ", " +
                newArrayCol/2 + "> which is outside the maze");

    //make sure the new row/col is adjacent
    else if (!adjacentTo(newArrayRow, newArrayCol))
        throw new IllegalMazeMoveException("trying to move from cell <" +  currentArrayRow/2 + ", " + currentArrayCol/2 +
                "> to non-adjacent cell <" + newArrayRow/2 + ", " + newArrayCol/2 + ">");

    //make sure there is not a wall in between
    else if (!openTo(newArrayRow, newArrayCol))
        throw new IllegalMazeMoveException("trying to move from cell <" +  currentArrayRow/2 + ", " + currentArrayCol/2 +
                "> to cell <" + newArrayRow/2 + ", " + newArrayCol/2 + "> and there is a wall in between");

    //if OK, move the current cell
    else
    {
        //if new ArrayRow is already in the path, then we are retreating from current location so
        //clear current location
        if (mazeArray[newArrayRow][newArrayCol] == 2)
            mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 0;

        currentArrayRow = newArrayRow;
        currentArrayCol = newArrayCol;                      //move current cell
        mazeArray[currentArrayRow][currentArrayCol] = 2;   //and show it as part of path
        success = true;

    }

    //return
    return success;
}

//-------- goalReached - returns true if the maze is solved (current location == goal)
public boolean goalReached()
{
    return (currentArrayRow == goalArrayRow && currentArrayCol == goalArrayCol);
}

//-------- getMazeArray - returns the mazeArray
public int[][] getMazeArray()
{
    return mazeArray;
}

//***********************************************************************

//This is Maze's enumerated data type: moves can be UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
public enum Direction
{
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}

//***********************************************************************

//MazeMoveException will be thrown when an illegal move is requested in the maze
public class IllegalMazeMoveException extends IllegalArgumentException
{
    //no data is needed - all inherited...

    //constructor - just do what the parent class would do if it received the String
    public IllegalMazeMoveException(String str)
    {
        super(str);
    }

    //no methods are needed - all inherited...
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure this is your main class and not the main class from your assignment?

Comment: I was given a Maze class and MazeDisplay. This code is to set up the maze and solve it.

Comment: post the missing classes here

Comment: You are able to post it with separate code block.

Answer (score 1):

The following does not look right:

```
(!visitedCells.contains(myCell.getX()) && !visitedCells.contains(myCell.getY()-1)))
```

Here, `visitedCells` is an `ArrayList<Point>`, but the above code looks for two separate `Integer`s.

Instead, you need to construct an instance of `Point`, and look for that, making sure `Point.equals()` is implemented to compare the coordinates.

This mistake is repeated in a few places.